# Java: Inserting a pair of elements into linked list

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, linked-list

I'm new to Java, I am trying to add a group of elements into a linked list, my interface contains add single, pair, triple. Here is what I have so far for the methods.

list is a linked list declared in constructor

```
public void addSingle(E item) {
    list.add(item);      
}

public void addPair(E first, E second) {
   E one = first;
   E two = second;

   LinkedList<E> pairList;

   pairList = new LinkedList<E>();

   pairList.add(one);
   pairList.add(two);

   list.addAll(pairList);
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lists<String> linkdList = new ConcreteList<String>();
    linkdList.addSingle("allan");

    linkdList.addPair("abc","def");
```

}

this adds everything into linkdList but need it to be able to differentiate between single and pair.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: With 'differentiate between single and pair', do you mean it has to be able to know afterwards whether an element was added using the `addSingle` method or the `addPair` method?

Comment: @Ghostkeeper He wants to treat a pair as a single object in the linkedlist. I'd recommend a wrapper class or an interface.

Comment: Or you could use a list for each entry in the main list. So the whole data structure becomes a list of lists. This has the advantage that it still works if someday it needs to store more than just singles, pairs and triples. I think it would also be easier to traverse.

Comment: @RetoKoradi that is exactly what I want to do, not sure how though

Comment: Ok, I can try an answer. Java is not my primary language, and I don't have a development environment at hand. So it might have a few syntax errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is untested, but I hope it still illustrates how this can be implemented. The idea here is to make the main data structure a list of lists. So each entry in the main list is a list with 1, 2, or 3 strings.

```
public void addSingle(E item) {
    LinkedList<E> singleList = new LinkedList<E>();
    singleList.add(item);

    list.add(singleList);
}

public void addPair(E first, E second) {
    LinkedList<E> pairList = new LinkedList<E>();
    pairList.add(first);
    pairList.add(second);

    list.add(pairList);
}

public void addTriple(E first, E second, E third) {
    LinkedList<E> tripleList = new LinkedList<E>();
    tripleList.add(first);
    tripleList.add(second);
    tripleList.add(third);

    list.add(tripleList);
}

private List<List<E>> list = new LinkedList<List<E>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a simple base type and two derived types : it might look like this (probably has some syntax errors and typos...)

```
class <E> ListEntry<E> {
}

class <E> SingleValueListEntry extends ListEntry<E> {
  E value;
  SingleValueListEntry(E value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class <E> DoubleValueListEntry extends ListEntry<E> {
  E first;
  E second
  SingleValueListEntry(E first, E second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }
}

public static void <E> addSingle(List<ListEntry<E>> list, E item) {
    list.add( new SingleListEntry(item));      
}

public static void <E> addPair(List<ListEntry<E>> list, E first, E second) {
   list.add( new DoubleListEntry(first,second) );
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lists<ListEntry<E>> list = new ConcreteList<ListEntry<E>>();
    addSingle(list, "allan");

    addPair(list, "abc","def");

    for( ListEntry<String> e : list ) {
       if( e instanceof SingleValueListEntry<String> ) {
             SingleValueListEntry<String> v = (SingleValueListEntry<String>)e;
             System.println("Single value : "+v.value);
       }
       if( e instanceof DoubleValueListEntry<String> ) {
             DoubleValueListEntry<String> v = (DoubleValueListEntry<String>)e;
             System.println("Single value : "+v.first+", "+v.second);
       }
   }
}
```